# Transfer big file from PC to a Pocket PC

Tags: c#, pocketpc, file-transfer

I need to transfer a big file from PC to PPC (Pocket PC) but I can't use RAPI.

I need to:

1. Convert an .sdf (big) file to a binary format
2. Transfer to PPC (through a Web service)
3. In PPC convert from binary to .sdf

The problem is that in PPC I got an exception "out of memory" (in big file). With a small file it works excellently.

What can I do? Maybe I can send the file in slices?

Comment: Personal Computer and Pocket Personal Computer, I'm guessing?

Comment: PC = Personal Computer, PPC - Pocket PC (Windows Mobile)

Comment: Why don't you post the code you're using now?  As others have noted, you obviously want to read it in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

What Conrad said, you need to send the file in smaller sizes, depending on what kind pf PPC you have. That could be as small as few mb, and then write to either a storage card or the main memory.
I personaly use FTP to transfer "big" files ( Ranging in the hundreds of mb ) to transfer to my PPC, but im sure you can use any other solution you may desire. But you need to research the limits of your target PPC, they often have limited memory,storage and CPU.
There is also a built in http downloader class in the .net compact framework you can use.